# Dir.exist? does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svn, filesystems

I have an issue while checking if a directory exists.

I'm writing a small Ruby app that performs a svn checkout from a repository, and then looks in the working copy to see if a certain directory exists.

I have a SVNClient class that performs the svn operations, calling the command line client using `open3.popen3` (I have not found any ruby gem to work with svn):

```
class SVNClient
    require 'open3'

    def initialize(repoUrl, wcPath, username, password)
        @repoUrl = repoUrl
        @wcPath = wcPath
        @username = username
        @password = password
    end

    def checkout
        cmd = "svn co %s %s  --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username %s --password %s" % [@repoUrl, @wcPath, @username, @password]
        stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
    end

    def createDirIfNotExists(dirname)
        @subdirPath = @wcPath + "/" + dirname

        a = File.directory? @subdirPath
        b = File.exist? @subdirPath
        c = Dir.exist? @subdirPath
        Rails.logger.debug("#{a}")
        Rails.logger.debug("#{b}")
        Rails.logger.debug("#{c}")


        if !Dir.exist? @subdirPath
            Rails.logger.debug("#{@subdirPath} does not exist")
            Dir.mkdir @subdirPath
        end
    end
end
```

This class is used like this:

```
        wcDir = "/the/workingcopy/dir"
        logger.debug("#{wcDir}")
        urlToCkeckout = "http://somerepo/path

        client = SVNClient.new(urlToCkeckout, wcDir, username, password)
        client.checkout
        client.createDirIfNotExists("subdir")
```

Now, I am doing some tests and I am sure that when I do the checkout, the `"subdir"` directory is inside the working copy directory. But in the `createDirIfNotExists` method, the `Dir.exist?` call returns false (and also  `File.directory?` and `File.exist?`), and I get the "... does not exists" log message.
Am I missing something obvious here? I have checked the permissions on the directories and they looks good.

By the way, the code is run inside a Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the block version of `open3.popen3` in my `checkout` method, to be sure that the command ends before checking for the dir existence:

```
        Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
            pid = wait_thr.pid # pid of the started process.
            Rails.logger.debug("#{pid}")
        end
```

Now, the call to `createDirIfNotExists` happens after the checkout has terminated, and so the directory is correctly found.